# Choosing a finish for a tusk/key/wedge that stays put

Tags: finishing, joinery

To ensure that a tusk stays put longer in a mortise, is the nature of the finish critical (assuming the piece is cut to a L:W ratio ~10:1)?

The particular type of construction i’m referring to is this one:

[image: tusked tenon]
*(image From “Illustrated Cabinetmaking” by Bill Hylton, sampled from [this site](https://studiomakedo.wordpress.com/category/projects-joints-and-connections/detail-locked-and-tusk-mortise-and-tenons-joints/))*

On other sites, found mixed user reports about [wax being inadequate](http://lumberjocks.com/topics/35733)

Comment: I think broadly speaking this is going to be a horses for courses kind of thing — what'll work well for one person won't for another (given differences in the species used, the wedge slope, the flatness and smoothness of the wedge and mortise surfaces as well as possibly exact grain orientation). Wherever there is slipping a little judicious sanding wouldn't hurt, and the hairspray trick as used on socket chisels may be of benefit too. I would expect wax to do the exact opposite of what is wanted since wax is usually used as a lubricant!

Comment: ok. so it’s not critical in any case it can be fixed with a bit of sanding afterwards. will try finish that matches legs.